# String escape and sprintf() function

Tags: php, sql

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s')",
         mysql_real_escape_string($name));
```

This is my registration code, I will check if the same username already exists in my database and I will convert everything in uppercase to avoid same names with different upper and lowercases (Pizza, pizza). I have 2 questions:

1) Now to prevent sql injection I use mysql_real_escape_string($name) but is this ok? Can I use variable in that function or must I use `$_POST['user']` ?

2) What exactly is `sprintf()` ? Why do I need it, why is there `'%s'` in it?

Comment: 1) It would be OK if you were not using the deprecated mysql extension; switch to something better like mysqli or PDO (where you won't have to inject like this in the first place because they support bound parameters). 2) Read the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a variable name. `sprintf()` is used for string formatting and `%s` is type specifier in this case: `string`

Comment: but why would I want to format my sql string statement?

Comment: Is it to protect my vital information in that string?

Answer (score 1):

1) It is okay if you use mysqli_real_escape_string instead of mysql_real_escape_string.

2) sprintf() has a lot of formatting capabilities so you can do more than just insert variable values in strings. `%s` is a placeholder for a formatted string in sprintf(). Read the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: 1) It's best to use mysqli_real_escape_string if your using the MySQLi library. If your using MySQL_* library.. Switch to MySQli.

Comment: I am a  bit of a noob and if I use mysqli instead of  mysql the code doesn't work at all...